# How does std::execution::par_unseq handle remove_if on a vector?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17

I have a case where I need to remove elements from a vector if they meet some criteria, which is determined by a function. The layout of my code looks like this:

```
  auto firstToErase = std::remove_if( myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), [&]( const Obj &obj) {
      return isEntryInvalid( obj );
    } );

  myVec.erase( firstToErase, myVec.end() );
```

This performs the erasure in two steps. One to identify which entries must be removed, another to actually remove them. The erasure cannot be done in parallel, but the identification of entries to be removed can. Conveniently, C++17 offers *execution policies* to do this. That looks like this:

```
  auto firstToErase = std::remove_if( std::execution::par_unseq, myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), [&]( const Obj &obj) {
      return isEntryInvalid( obj );
    } );

  myVec.erase( firstToErase, myVec.end() );
```

I have this already written, and they work fantastic. And par_unseq provides a roughly 5x performance improvement. However:

**How does that remove_if operation work when std::execution::par_unseq is passed?**

A naive approach I can think of would be to hand each `std::thread` its own `std::unordered_set<int>` that indicate the indices which need to be erased. Then, once all threads finish, join them together into one large set. (Though I'm not sure if that's compatible with what `erase()` takes.)

But the problem with that approach is that if *many* removals need to happen or if you're on a system with many threads, that final merge looks pretty ugly and would eat at the performance benefit. (At least in my experience with implementing a similar approach with `std::unordered_map`)

So clearly, that must not be what remove_if is doing!

How is this handled now? Is there a more clever solution GCC/Clang are using?

**To clarify, I don't need a solution to a problem per-se. I already have working code. I just want to know how remove_if is working under the hood.**

Answer (score 1):

What I would do was to have each worker thread do a sequential `std::remove_if` on a subrange of the given range, then [`std::move_backward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move_backward) the "live" portions of those ranges. This does mean each element is moved twice, but that's allowed.

As a sketch:

```
vector<subrange> subranges = /* divide [first, last) into thread_count sequential subranges */
vector<tuple<iterator, future<iterator>>> futures;
for (auto s : subranges) {
    futures.emplace_back(s.begin(), async(remove_if, s.begin(), s.end(), pred)); // or some other parallel evaluation
}
for (auto & [s_first, fut] : futures) {
     first = move_backward(s_first, fut.get(), first);
}
return first;
```

Comment: I don't follow what you're talking about with std::unordered_set, but that's not critical. 

After thinking on it, I think you're right. remove_if with par_unseq must be doing something similar to this. Thanks. I guess I didn't even realize a "range" type must exist somewhere. There's no need to merge the results at the end since they have no overlap and are sequential, which saves time.

Comment: @TylerShellberg oh yes, there is potential for `std::bad_alloc` from unspecified shenanigans

Answer (score -1):

Removing elements in parallel would end up in undefined results. You could separate the search from the removal instruction and wrap the removal in a `std::mutex`, but that would run the removals itself sequentially.

`std::remove_if` catches that issue (and other stuff like [data races](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)) like this:
The implementation of a parallel `std::remove_if` splits the work to chunks of the array per thread sequentially. Let's assume our vector is 100 elements large and we have 10 threads. Thread 1 runs sequentialy from 0 to 9, thread 2 runs from 10 to 19, ... When this is done all partial results are merged.

The important part (MSVC implementation) looks like this

```
_TRY_BEGIN
_Static_partitioned_remove_if2 _Operation{_Hw_threads, _Count, _UFirst, _Pass_fn(_Pred)};
_Run_chunked_parallel_work(_Hw_threads, _Operation);
_Seek_wrapped(_First, _Operation._Results);
return _First;
_CATCH(const _Parallelism_resources_exhausted&)
// fall through to serial case below
_CATCH_END
```

Instead I recommend to perform a parallel sort like `std::sort(std::execution::par_unseq, ...);` by predicate (your `if` condition) to move all items to be removed to the end. Then reduce the length using `std::vector::resize` to the index of the first element matching your criteria.
In parallel scenarios having numeric data you might want to use [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. std::remove_if already identifies all the indices which must be removed, and then they can be safely removed in a non-parallel way using std::erase.

I am asking about *how* that remove_if operation is done in parallel. Not the erasure itself.

Comment: I have added some example code to the post which may clarify what I am asking.

Comment: @TylerShellberg I added the relevant source snipped (of MSVC, no GCC/clang at hand currently) and tried to explain a little.

Comment: I don't think that sorting should be recommended for the purpose of "erase_if" because sorting usually introduces more time complexity and more move(swap) operations.

Comment: @VainMan that's true for sequential execution. Using paralellism, especially with high degree of parallelization (e.g. SIMD, SIMT), this looks different, where we want to avoid sequential dependencies of removal (including re-linking). In parallel we are just limited by the amount of atomic swap operations on same memory (+ hardware limitations like latency, bandwidth), which can run totally independent, mostly depending on sort algorithm. A brief comparison can be found here: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1511/1511.03404.pdf

Comment: @ChrisG. That paper compares only sorting algorithms. I cannot find any words saying that it is faster than remove_if when used for removal.

Comment: @ChrisG. Did you forget that  remove_if also have an overload for parallel execution?

Comment: @VainMan the source snipped was taken from the parallel overload (MSVC implementation). Feel free to write an improved answer. The link shows various graphs comparing multiple algorithms measured in e.g. million / second using different distributions and data length. Indeed it's not written, but visualized in graphs.